# How to start activity only after user clicks ok on AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog and I only want the next Activity to start after I have click "OK". The problem is in my method, I have local variables attached to my intent and I cannot put in the onCreateDialog method.

```
//local variable created
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();    
for(int i=0; i<studentList.size(); i++){
    students.add(studentList.get(i).getName());
}

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                     new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.popup_theme));
alertDialog.setTitle("Select Game");           
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("3x3", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

    //I want the new Activity to start only after user clicks ok.
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
    //Local variable, undefined, cannot reference 
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("students", students);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;  
    }        
}); 
alertDialog.show();
```

Is there any way I can prevent the code after `showDialog()` from running until the user clicks OK? I have local variable that I need to put inside the intent.

Comment: The code you have looks correct, it will start the activity when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a right way but I did a 'hack' by making `students` a global variable. Would welcome better answers.

Answer (score 6):

use this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                         new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.popup_theme));
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Game");         
    alertDialog.setMessage("[ Choose Puzzle Matrix ]");      
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("3x3", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(((Dialog) dialog).getContext(), Matrix3x3.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);    
        return;  
        }        
    });      
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Yes I have this. I am unable to put username in my intent because it is a local variable.

Comment: u want transfer data from one activity to another.

Comment: Yes, thats right. I did a 'hack' by making students a global variable.. any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Make `students` variable `final`.

```
final ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
```